# setText to Jlabel with function

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener, jlabel

I am trying to `settext` to `JLabel` with a function.

The checkResults function is not working for some reason I still get errors. I have 2 classes

`Driver` and `MathProblems`

Driver Class

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Driver extends MathProblems {

    MathProblems answers = new MathProblems();
    MathProblems problems = new MathProblems();
    private static final Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    String s = "Welcome Students!";
    String b = "Start!";
    private JFrame f;
    private JPanel p;

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    JButton b1 = new JButton(b);

    JLabel jl = new JLabel(s);

    int i;

    public Driver () {      
        gui();  
    }

    public void gui() { 
        f = new JFrame("Flash Card Program");       
        p = new JPanel();   
        f.setLayout( new GridLayout( 2, 1 ) );
        f.add(jl);
        f.add(p);
        p.setLayout( new GridLayout( 2, 1 ) );
        p.add(b1);

        jl.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);

        // pack the frame for better cross platform support
        f.pack();
        // Make it visible
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setSize(560,400); // default size is 0,0
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


        b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                if(b1.getText().equals("Click For Answer"))
                {
                    String s = in.nextLine();
                    int expected = Integer.parseInt(s);
                    answers.run();
                    jl.setText.(answers.checkResult());
                    String b = "Next Question";
                    b1.setText(b);
                }
                else
                {
                    problems.run();
                    jl.setText(problems.getQuestion());
                    String b = "Click For Answer";
                    b1.setText(b);

                }
          }
});
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
                new Driver();
           }
        });
    } // End main Method

} // End class Driver
```

MathProblems Class

```
import java.util.Random;

public class MathProblems {
     private static final int MAX_NUMBER = 10;
     private static final Random random = new Random();

     private int expected = 0;
     private String question = "";

     public void run() {
         final int a = random.nextInt(MAX_NUMBER);
         final int b = random.nextInt(MAX_NUMBER);

         final int type = random.nextInt(4);

         switch (type) {
             case 0: 
                 add(a, b);
                 break;
             case 1: 
                subtract(a, b);
                break;
             case 2:
                multiply(a, b);
                break;
             case 3:
                 divide(a, b);
                 break;
         }
     }

     private void add(final int a, final int b) {
         expected = a + b;

         askQuestion(a + " + " + b + " = ");
     }

     private void subtract(final int a, final int b) {
         expected = a - b;

         askQuestion(a + " - " + b + " = ");
     }

     private void multiply(final int a, final int b) {
         expected = a * b;

         askQuestion(a + " * " + b + " = ");
     }

     private void divide(final int a, final int b) {
         expected = a / b;

         askQuestion(a + " / " + b + " = ");
     }

     private  void askQuestion(final String question) {
         this.question = question;
     }  

     public String getQuestion() {
         return question;
     }

     public String checkResult(final int answer) {
         return Integer.toString(expected);
     }

}
```

Comment: Perhaps you should tell us the errors you get

Comment: the metho CheckResult Int is not applicable on this line  jl.setText.(answers.checkResult());

Comment: You don't seem to have a checkResult() method that doesn't take parameters. You do have a checkResult method that takes an int though.

Comment: yes it does take an int. so how would i write that line to Integer.toString???

Comment: um... pass an int into the method like the method expects, perhaps. Else how will the method magically return a String out of nothing?

Comment: ummm im sorry im not a professional java expert i'm learning would you mind showing me how to do this.

Comment: The parmeter to `checkResult()` method is 100% useless considering you never use it in the method. You are returning a String representation of your variable `expected`, not the parameter `answer`.

Comment: but that method returns the the result. which is called expected. If this is not correct then how would you suggest I return the value of the math problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented on your previous question:
You need to remove "problems.run()" from your first condition in the listener, otherwise the "answer" you get will be for the next question, and so on. Also, consider using doubles in your divide() method, by using ints you will lose the decimals.

Answer (score 0):

I think jl.setText requires a string a string value instead of passing an integer.

In your case perhaps

```
jl.setText(answers.checkResult(Integer.toString(expected)));
```

and change

```
public String checkResult(String answer) {
     return Integer.toString(expected);
 }
```

Although Im not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve here

Comment: I have edited this to at least work for you. Please provide your intentions of the code for checkResult.

Comment: i am trying to post the int in result which is the answer to the math problems to the jlabel

Comment: I dont know why someone down voted you. I upvoted. Thank you for your help. this fixed the error but it still does not work. the program just locks up after the first click

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this

```
jl.setText.(answers.checkResult());
```

should be this:

```
jl.setText(answers.checkResult(expected));
```

this:

```
public String checkResult(final int answer) {
         return Integer.toString(expected);
     }
```

should be something like this:

```
   public int getAnswer() {
         return expected;
   }
```

**NOW here's the REAL issue**

You shouldn't be doing this:

```
String s = in.nextLine();
```

You should add a textbox to the form to enter the value, that's why it's freezing on you.  Scanner is used for command line input output

Change this:

```
String s = in.nextLine();
int expected = Integer.parseInt(s);
```

to

```
int expected = problems.getAnswer();
```

Comment: Really I just want the answer to post. There is no place for user to enter asnswrr. I just want a question to apprsrbthen the abswer on the next click.

Comment: What did I need to change to jut get the answer expected to appear int he jlabel ?

Comment: Okay, if you want the answer, you'll need to create a method on MathProblems called getAnswer, I'll update real quick

Comment: jl.setText is still getting errors offering to change to setToolType        b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                if(b1.getText().equals("Click For Answer"))
                {
                 int expected = problems.getAnswer();
                    jl.setText(problems.getAnswer();
                    String b = "Next Question";
                    b1.setText(b);
                }
                else
                {

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem is expected needs to be

```
 @Override
 public String toString(){
 return Integer.toString(expected);
 }
```

Then it needs to be set to JLabel like this,

```
jl.setText(problems.toString());
```