# @Overide toString with Integer. Then setText to JLabel

Tags: java, tostring

expected holds the answer to a math problem.

being a int I am sending `toString`

```
   @Override
     public String toString(){
     return Integer.toString(expected);
     }
```

Then I am `setText` to a `JLabel`

```
 jl.setText(toString());
```

When the program runs instead of showing the answer it shows the Hash.

I am assuming this has to be with `Integer.toString` But I am calling it in the toString method.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
Driver Class

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Driver extends MathProblems {

    MathProblems problems = new MathProblems();

    String s = "Welcome Students!";
    String b = "Start!";
    private JFrame f;
    private JPanel p;

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    JButton b1 = new JButton(b);

    JLabel jl = new JLabel(s);

    int i;

    public Driver () {      
        gui();  
    }

    public void gui() { 
        f = new JFrame("Flash Card Program");       
        p = new JPanel();   
        f.setLayout( new GridLayout( 2, 1 ) );
        f.add(jl);
        f.add(p);
        p.setLayout( new GridLayout( 2, 1 ) );
        p.add(b1);

        jl.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);

        // pack the frame for better cross platform support
        f.pack();
        // Make it visible
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setSize(560,400); // default size is 0,0
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


        b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                if(b1.getText().equals("Click For Answer"))
                {
                    problems.run();
                    jl.setText(toString());
                    String b = "Next Question";
                    b1.setText(b);
                }
                else
                {
                    problems.run();
                    jl.setText(problems.getQuestion());
                    String b = "Click For Answer";
                    b1.setText(b);

                }
            }
        });
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
                new Driver();
           }
        });
    } // End main Method

} // End class Driver

MathProblems

import java.util.Random;

public class MathProblems {
     private static final int MAX_NUMBER = 10;
     private static final Random random = new Random();

     private int expected = 0;
     private String question = "";

     public void run() {
         final int a = random.nextInt(MAX_NUMBER);
         final int b = random.nextInt(MAX_NUMBER);

         final int type = random.nextInt(4);

         switch (type) {
             case 0: 
                 add(a, b);
                 break;
             case 1: 
                subtract(a, b);
                break;
             case 2:
                multiply(a, b);
                break;
             case 3:
                 divide(a, b);
                 break;
         }
     }

     private void add(final int a, final int b) {
         expected = a + b;

         askQuestion(a + " + " + b + " = ");
     }

     private void subtract(final int a, final int b) {
         expected = a - b;

         askQuestion(a + " - " + b + " = ");
     }

     private void multiply(final int a, final int b) {
         expected = a * b;

         askQuestion(a + " * " + b + " = ");
     }

     private void divide(final int a, final int b) {
         expected = a / b;

         askQuestion(a + " / " + b + " = ");
     }

     private  void askQuestion(final String question) {
         this.question = question;
     }  

     public String getQuestion() {
         return question;
     }

     public int getAnswer() {
         return expected;
   }

     @Override
     public String toString(){
     return Integer.toString(expected);
     }
}
```

Comment: You're not showing nearly enough code. My suspicion is that the `toString()` override is on a different class from the one in which you're calling `setText`. Perhaps you mean `jl.setText(someObject.toString())`.

Comment: You can use String.valueOf(expected);

Comment: yes it is in a different class. I added all my code

Comment: @Arjit you mean like this?   jl.setText(toString()); instead do jl.setText.String.valueOf(expected); ???

Comment: You need to remove "problems.run()" from your first condition in the listener, otherwise the "answer" you get will be for the next question, and so on. Also, consider using doubles in your divide() method, by using ints you will lose the decimals.

Comment: @Martin ahhhh thank you a ton... You fixed it. Post that answer here so I can accept it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23123201/settext-to-jlabel-with-function/23161435#23161435

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change it to:

```
if(b1.getText().equals("Click For Answer"))
            {
                problems.run();
                jl.setText(problems.toString()); // note the change here
                String b = "Next Question";
                b1.setText(b);
            }
            else
            {
                problems.run();
                jl.setText(problems.getQuestion()); // and how you got it right here
                String b = "Click For Answer";
                b1.setText(b);

            }
```

Comment: Thank you this fixed it... Now I have another problem. haha The answers are not correct with the math problems