# Return the value of a method into a JLabel

Tags: java, user-interface, methods

I am trying to return the value of calculate in the first block of code to my JLabel in my GUI (which will be in the second block of code that I paste.

First block of code-

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SpeedingTicketClass {

Scanner scan=new Scanner (System.in); //Creating a scanner to read in users input of the speed limit and their speed.
//Variables used to store users input of the speed limit and the speed they are going.
int speedLimit=0;
int usersSpeed=0;
String usersName;

//Method being used to obtain the speed limit of the area with a do/while loop to make sure a correct speed limit is entered.
public int getSpeedLimit() {
    do {
        System.out.println("Please enter the speed limit: ");
        speedLimit=scan.nextInt();
    }while (!(speedLimit==70 || speedLimit==20| speedLimit==30 || speedLimit==40 || speedLimit==50 || speedLimit==60));
    return speedLimit;
}

//Method being used to obtain the speed in which a user is going at.
public int getUsersSpeed() {
    System.out.println("Please enter your speed: ");
    usersSpeed=scan.nextInt();
    return usersSpeed;
}

public String getUsersInformation() {
    usersName=scan.nextLine();
    return usersName;
}

//Method being used to calculate the speed of the users inputs and what fine they will receive.
public String calculateSpeed() {

    String calculate="";
    if (speedLimit==20 && usersSpeed>20 && usersSpeed<=24) {
        calculate="Just a warning. Please do not speed again!";
    }
    else if (speedLimit==20 && usersSpeed>24 && usersSpeed<30) {
        calculate=("Fine. £50 to pay!");
    }
    else if (speedLimit==20 && usersSpeed>=30 && usersSpeed<35) {
        calculate=("Fine. £100 to pay!");
    }
    else if (speedLimit==20 && usersSpeed>=35 && usersSpeed<40) {
        calculate=("3 points on your license and £150 fine to pay!");
    }
    else if (speedLimit==20 && usersSpeed>=40) {
        calculate=("Disqualifed and a £1000 fine to pay!");
    } 
    else if (speedLimit==20 && usersSpeed<=20) {
        calculate=("You are within the speed limit!");
    } //20mph IF statement

    if (speedLimit==30 && usersSpeed>30 && usersSpeed<=34) {
        calculate=("Just a warning. Please do not speed again!");
    }
    else if (speedLimit==30 && usersSpeed>34 && usersSpeed<40) {
        calculate=("Fine. £50 to pay!");
    }
    else if (speedLimit==30 && usersSpeed>=40 && usersSpeed<45) {
        calculate=("Fine. £100 to pay!");
    }
    else if (speedLimit==30 && usersSpeed>=45 && usersSpeed<50) {
        calculate=("3 points on your license and £150 fine to pay!");
    }
    else if (speedLimit==30 && usersSpeed>=50) {
        calculate=("Disqualifed and a £1000 fine to pay!");
    }
    else if (speedLimit==30 && usersSpeed<=30) {
        calculate=("You are within the speed limit!");
    } //30mph IF statement

    if (speedLimit==40 && usersSpeed>40 && usersSpeed<=44) {
        calculate=("Just a warning. Please do not speed again!");
    }
    else if (speedLimit==40 && usersSpeed>44 && usersSpeed<50) {
        calculate=("Fine. £50 to pay!");
    }
    else if (speedLimit==40 && usersSpeed>=50 && usersSpeed<55) {
        calculate=("Fine. £100 to pay!");
    }
    else if (speedLimit==40 && usersSpeed>=55 && usersSpeed<60) {
        calculate=("3 points on your license and £150 fine to pay!");
    }
    else if (speedLimit==40 && usersSpeed>=60) {
        calculate=("Disqualifed and a £1000 fine to pay!");
    }
    else if (speedLimit==40 && usersSpeed<=40) {
        calculate=("You are within the speed limit!");
    } //40mph IF statement

    if (speedLimit==50 && usersSpeed>50 && usersSpeed<=54) {
        calculate=("Just a warning. Please do not speed again!");
    }
    else if (speedLimit==50 && usersSpeed>54 && usersSpeed<60) {
        calculate=("Fine. £50 to pay!");
    }
    else if (speedLimit==50 && usersSpeed>=60 && usersSpeed<65) {
        calculate=("Fine. £100 to pay!");
    }
    else if (speedLimit==50 && usersSpeed>=65 && usersSpeed<70) {
        calculate=("3 points on your license and £150 fine to pay!");
    }
    else if (speedLimit==50 && usersSpeed>=70) {
        calculate=("Disqualifed and a £1000 fine to pay!");
    }
    else if (speedLimit==50 && usersSpeed<=50) {
        calculate=("You are within the speed limit!");
    } //50mph IF statement

    if (speedLimit==60 && usersSpeed>60 && usersSpeed<=64) {
        calculate=("Just a warning. Please do not speed again!");
    }
    else if (speedLimit==60 && usersSpeed>64 && usersSpeed<70) {
        calculate=("Fine. £50 to pay!");
    }
    else if (speedLimit==60 && usersSpeed>=70 && usersSpeed<75) {
        calculate=("Fine. £100 to pay!");
    }
    else if (speedLimit==60 && usersSpeed>=75 && usersSpeed<80) {
        calculate=("3 points on your license and £150 fine to pay!");
    }
    else if (speedLimit==60 && usersSpeed>=80) {
        calculate=("Disqualifed and a £1000 fine to pay!");
    }
    else if (speedLimit==60 && usersSpeed<=60) {
        calculate=("You are within the speed limit!");
    } //60mph IF statement

    if (speedLimit==70 && usersSpeed>70 && usersSpeed<=74) {
        calculate=("Just a warning. Please do not speed again!");
    }
    else if (speedLimit==70 && usersSpeed>74 && usersSpeed<80) {
        calculate=("Fine. £50 to pay!");
    }
    else if (speedLimit==70 && usersSpeed>=80 && usersSpeed<85) {
        calculate=("Fine. £100 to pay!");
    }
    else if (speedLimit==70 && usersSpeed>=85 && usersSpeed<90) {
        calculate=("3 points on your license and £150 fine to pay!");
    }
    else if (speedLimit==70 && usersSpeed>=90) {
        calculate=("Disqualifed and a £1000 fine to pay!");
    }
    else if (speedLimit==70 && usersSpeed<=70) {
        calculate=("You are within the speed limit!");
    } //70mph IF statement  

    if (speedLimit>70) {
        calculate=("Please enter a speed limit which is 70mph or under!");
    }
    System.out.println(calculate);
    return calculate;
}
}
```

Now below is my second code of the GUI-

```
//Imports
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class SpeedingTicketGUI {

private JLabel lblInfo;
private JLabel lblWelcomeText;
private JLabel lblEnterName;
private JLabel lblEnterSpeedLimit;
private JLabel lblEnterYourSpeed;
private JLabel lblResultOfCalculate;
private JLabel lblFinalResult;
private JButton btnCalculate;
private JButton btnClose;
private JTextField txtEnterName;
private JTextField txtEnterSpeedLimit;
private JTextField txtEnterUsersSpeed;
private JPanel panel;
private JFrame frame;

private SpeedingTicketClass speedTicket=new SpeedingTicketClass();

Font f=new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 80);
Font r=new Font ("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 100);

public SpeedingTicketGUI(){
    createForm();
    createButtons();
    createLabels();
    createInputFields();

    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public void createForm() {
    frame=new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(800,600);
    frame.setTitle("Speeding Ticket");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    panel=new JPanel();
    panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    panel.setLayout(null);
}

public void createButtons() {
    btnCalculate= new JButton("Calculate");
    btnCalculate.setBounds(158,307,114,27);
    btnCalculate.addActionListener(new CalculateHandler());
    panel.add(btnCalculate);

    btnClose= new JButton ("Close");
    btnClose.setBounds(319, 307, 114, 27);
    btnClose.addActionListener(new ExitHandler());
    panel.add(btnClose);
}

public void createInputFields() {
    txtEnterName=new JTextField();
    txtEnterName.setBounds(158, 72, 145, 27);
    txtEnterName.addActionListener(new UsersInfoHandler());
    panel.add(txtEnterName);

    txtEnterSpeedLimit=new JTextField();
    txtEnterSpeedLimit.setBounds(158, 109, 145, 27);
    txtEnterSpeedLimit.addActionListener(new SpeedLimitHandler());
    panel.add(txtEnterSpeedLimit);

    txtEnterUsersSpeed=new JTextField();
    txtEnterUsersSpeed.setBounds(158, 139, 145, 27);
    txtEnterSpeedLimit.addActionListener(new UsersSpeedHandler());
    panel.add(txtEnterUsersSpeed);
}

public void createLabels() {
    lblWelcomeText=new JLabel ("Welcome!");
    lblWelcomeText.setBounds(211, 16, 169, 21);
    panel.add(lblWelcomeText);

    lblInfo=new JLabel ("Check what fine you are required to settle here.");
    lblInfo.setBounds(158,37,275,38);
    panel.add(lblInfo);

    lblEnterName=new JLabel ("Enter your name:");
    lblEnterName.setBounds(40, 75, 102, 21);
    panel.add(lblEnterName);

    lblEnterSpeedLimit=new JLabel ("Enter the speed limit:");
    lblEnterSpeedLimit.setBounds(28, 112, 126, 21);
    panel.add(lblEnterSpeedLimit);

    lblEnterYourSpeed=new JLabel ("Enter your speed:");
    lblEnterYourSpeed.setBounds(38, 142, 106, 21);
    panel.add(lblEnterYourSpeed);

    lblResultOfCalculate=new JLabel ("Result:");
    lblResultOfCalculate.setBounds(60, 201, 63, 21);
    panel.add(lblResultOfCalculate);

    lblFinalResult=new JLabel("-Penalty will appear here-");
    lblFinalResult.setBounds(158, 201, 145, 21);
    panel.add(lblFinalResult);
}

//Action Listener to calculate the users speed
class CalculateHandler implements ActionListener{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent arg0) {
        speedTicket.calculateSpeed();
        lblFinalResult.setText(String.valueOf(speedTicket.calculateSpeed()));
    }
}

class SpeedLimitHandler implements ActionListener{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent arg0) {
        speedTicket.getSpeedLimit();
    }
}

/* UserInfoHandler used to obtain the users name so the information can be written to a file
 for viewing at a later date. */

class UsersInfoHandler implements ActionListener{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent arg0) {
        speedTicket.getUsersInformation();
    }
}

//UserSpeedHandler used to obtain the speed that the user enters into the TextArea.
class UsersSpeedHandler implements ActionListener{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent arg0) {
        speedTicket.getUsersSpeed();
    }
}

//ExitHandler used to control what happens when a user presses the 'Close' button.
class ExitHandler implements ActionListener{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        int n=JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame, "Are you sure you want to exit?", null, JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

        if (n==JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}

public static void main (String[] args) {
    new SpeedingTicketGUI();
}
}
```

Please could someone help me as I have tried time and time again to make it work but it still isn't.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [setText to Jlabel with function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23123201/settext-to-jlabel-with-function)

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like `if (usersSpeed >= (!speedLimit + 20) && usersSpeed <= (!speedLimit + 40)` and so on for all your selections.

Comment: What has that got to do with the returning the calculate on the GUI?

Comment: Sorry newbie here

Comment: Improves efficiency.

Comment: @Jack You know what, I'm not saying your question is not in the right format, but

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow, a website where you can get help on specific problems with code. Start with the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and what questions are [suitable for asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and which ones are [not](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). You might also want to check out [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).